# How to check for only errors in swift result?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift has this result enum;

```
enum Result<Success, Failure> where Failure : Error {

/// A success, storing a `Success` value.
case success(Success)

/// A failure, storing a `Failure` value.
case failure(Failure)
}
```

and I don't know how to only check for errors.

Lets say I load an image into an ImageView and it returns a result, but I don't need the `.success(let _)` and I only want to check for `.failure(let error)`:

```
{ result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let _):
      print("I DONT NEED SUCCESS")
    case .failure(let error):
      print("ERROR")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if case` instead of a switch if you only want to pattern match a single case of an `enum` rather than matching all cases.

```
{ result in
    if case .failure(let error) = result {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```